# How to download EULA and show it at runtime in WiX installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX installer project. As per the requirement, I have to download the EULA  from a web server at runtime and show it at install time. How can we achieve this?
I tried to use custom action but no luck in that.

Comment: Can you change the application to do this on launch? Potentially with a link to a URL containing the latest version? (to avoid download failures due to firewall issues)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an blog post about 11 years ago that describes this:

http://blog.iswix.com/2008/07/dynamic-windows-installer-ui.html

Basically MSI has the concept of temporary data as discussed here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/sql-syntax

I've not tested this but it appears that UPDATE doesn't support TEMPORARY but INSERT INTO does.

The concept is you build your MSI  and place template RTF in the ScrollableText control.  Define a control condition so that the control is invisible if a property is set.

Then in a custom action scheduled before the WelcomeDlg you download the replacement RTF from the web service and dynamically define a control on the dialog with a replacement RTF and a condtrol condition so that the control is visible if the property is set.   Finally set the property to override the one control with the other.

But honestly... I'm not sure I'd bother doing this.   First there are ways of using a HyperLink to offboard the EULA from the installer  and/or remove the EULA from the installer and have the application show it on first run like Stain suggested.

Finally there are considerations such as silent installation and offline installations  that raise other concerns with this design.

That said... if you really want to do it... that is how it would be done.

Comment: I like to have applications show the EULA, but I forgot to mention that you probably need an "always on top" dialog, or some better means of making sure users actually see the EULA properly and reliably - without bugging them too much (show once per-user only, and no confusing check boxes and options). A classic disaster was an application that couldn't be used before the EULA was accepted, and the EULA showed up underneath the main window at times. Massive support desk effort to deal with it.